# function ibv_get_cq_event() does not return after destrcution

Tags: linux, infiniband, rdma

The function ibv_get_cq_event() block and never return even after destruction all resources.

I do init all InfiniBand resources, launch ibv_get_cq_event in separate thread, then destroy all InfiniBand resources but ibv_get_cq_event never returns.

What is the proper initialization and destruction IB (RDMA)?

Answer (score 1):

Blocking in `ibv_get_cq_event()` and then trying to destroy your resources is roughly the equivalent of creating a socket, blocking in `read()` and then calling `close()` on the socket in a different thread.  In fact internally a completion channel is really just a file descriptor, and `ibv_get_cq_event()` is pretty much just a wrapper around `read()`.  In both cases, the `read()` holds a reference on the file and the kernel won't wake up the `read()` just because someone else called `close()`.

There are at least two reasonable ways to handle your situation:

- Before trying to clean up IB resources, send a signal to the thread blocked in `read()` to wake it up.
- use `fcntl` to set `O_NONBLOCK` on `comp_channel->fd` and then use an event loop with `poll()` or `epoll` to known when the completion channel is readable.  Only call `read()` when an event is there, and stop your event loop when tearing down the RDMA resources.